# form in magento2?

Tags: php, magento2.2

I have create one textarea in custom form.

And also set max_length from admin configuration for textarea ..

I want to add displayed massege "comment is too long" in template file.

```
<form autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('comment is too long') ?>" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("sales/ordercomment/index", ['order_id' => $orderId]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
        <section class="admin__page-section">
            <div class="admin__page-section-title">
                <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Comment') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-content">
                <textarea  rows="3"
                           cols="50"
                           id="order-comment"
                           name="order"
                         maxlength="<?php echo $helper->getMaxLength();?>"
                          data-validate="{required:true}"
                           class="admin__control-textarea"> <?php echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($comment)); ?></textarea>           
            </div> 
            <div class="admin__page-section-content">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </form>
```

Comment: Plz share your code which you have tried.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: are you want to set text  comment is too long as placeholder in your textarea

Comment: yes ................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have placed at wrong place your data-hasrequired attribute. you
>   need to put with fieldset tag instead of form tag.

```
<form autocomplete="off" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("sales/ordercomment/index", ['order_id' => $orderId]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <fieldset class="fieldset comment" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('comment is too long') ?>">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
        <section class="admin__page-section">
            <div class="admin__page-section-title">
                <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Order Comment') ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-content">
                <textarea  rows="3"
                           cols="50"
                           id="order-comment"
                           name="order"
                         maxlength="<?php echo $helper->getMaxLength();?>"
                          data-validate="{required:true}"
                           class="admin__control-textarea"> <?php echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($comment)); ?></textarea>           
            </div> 
            <div class="admin__page-section-content">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </section>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```